# Ubuntu 18.04.2 sometimes hangs from Suspend or reboot

Tags: boot

About half the time my workstation boots fine. The other half, it hangs on the purple logo screen with the progress light moving endlessly across the five dots. The work-around that I have been using is to power off and restart. After the 2nd or 3rd restart it will boot on to the login screen.

Coming out of Suspend, the desktop hangs on the beaver sketch screen showing a Power notification, sometimes with other notifications. It doesn't matter what keyboard key I press, the screen just stays the same.

The symptoms are close to: "Ubuntu 18.04.2 boot stuck on purple screen after updates." But the bootup progress lights are not showing on this related issue. And the suggested fixes are for Asus laptops running Intel chips. I'm using an older stand alone Hp workstation with an AMD Sempron processor. Its a simple single-OS desktop.

I've completely reinstalled ubuntu twice, with no change. I don't see the issue using my bootable thumb drives. I wouldn't mind any kind of a work around, like using a usb thumb drive with boot files that will still let the machine boot to the local hard drive. Thanks for any help someone will contribute.

Graphics card: AMD® Rs880

(output from) sudo lshw -numeric -C display

*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RS880 [Radeon HD 4200] [1002:9710]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] [1002]
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:01:05.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:1100(size=256) memory:f0100000-f010ffff memory:f0000000-f00fffff memory:c0000-dffff

(output from)  sudo lshw -html > mySpecs.html

id: 
sff
description:    Low Profile Desktop Computer
product:    HP Compaq 6005 Pro SFF PC (SK557UC#ABA)
vendor:     Hewlett-Packard
serial:     2UA1520P0G
width:  64 bits
capabilities:   smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall32
configuration:
administrator_password  =   disabled
boot    =   normal
chassis =   low-profile
family  =   103C_53307F
power-on_password   =   disabled
sku =   SK557UC#ABA
uuid    =   8DA95630-EA31-E111-BBD8-38BA8C492C41
id: 
core
description:    Motherboard
product:    3047h
vendor:     Hewlett-Packard
physical id:
0
serial:     2UA1520P0G
id: 
firmware
description:    BIOS
vendor:     Hewlett-Packard
physical id:
1
version:    786G6 v01.15
date:   08/02/2011
size:   128KiB
capacity:   960KiB
capabilities:   pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
id: 
cpu
description:    CPU
product:    AMD Sempron(tm) 145 Processor
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
physical id:
5
bus info:
cpu@0
version:    AMD Sempron(tm) 145 Processor
slot:   XU1 PROCESSOR
size:   2800MHz
capacity:   2800MHz
width:  64 bits
clock:  200MHz
capabilities:   x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save cpufreq
configuration:
cores   =   1
enabledcores    =   1
threads =   1
id: 
cache:0
description:    L1 cache
physical id:
6
slot:   L1 Cache
size:   128KiB
capacity:   128KiB
clock:  1GHz (1.0ns)
capabilities:   pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
configuration:
level   =   1
id: 
cache:1
description:    L2 cache
physical id:
7
slot:   L2 Cache
size:   1MiB
capacity:   1MiB
clock:  1GHz (1.0ns)
capabilities:   pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
configuration:
level   =   2
id: 
memory:0
description:    System Memory
physical id:
39
slot:   System board or motherboard
id: 
bank:0
description:    DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
vendor:     JEDEC ID:
physical id:
0
slot:   XMM1
id: 
bank:1
description:    DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
product:    EBJ21UE8BDF0-DJ-F
vendor:     JEDEC ID:02 FE
physical id:
1
serial:     E3053C08
slot:   XMM2
size:   2GiB
width:  64 bits
clock:  1333MHz (0.8ns)
id: 
bank:2
description:    DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
product:    EBJ21UE8BDF0-DJ-F
vendor:     JEDEC ID:02 FE
physical id:
2
serial:     330557AF
slot:   XMM3
size:   2GiB
width:  64 bits
clock:  1333MHz (0.8ns)
id: 
bank:3
description:    DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
product:    8JTF25664AZ-1G4D1
vendor:     JEDEC ID:80 2C
physical id:
3
serial:     BAAF51E7
slot:   XMM4
size:   2GiB
width:  64 bits
clock:  1333MHz (0.8ns)
id: 
memory:1
description:    Flash Memory
physical id:
3a
slot:   System board or motherboard
capacity:   4MiB
id: 
bank
description:    Chip FLASH Non-volatile
physical id:
0
slot:   SYSTEM ROM
size:   1MiB
width:  2 bits
id: 
memory:2
physical id:
0
id: 
memory:3
physical id:
2
id: 
pci:0
description:    Host bridge
product:    RS880 Host Bridge
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
100
bus info:
pci@0000:00:00.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
configuration:
latency =   32
id: 
pci:0
description:    PCI bridge
product:    RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
1
bus info:
pci@0000:00:01.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   pci ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
resources:
ioport  :   1000(size=4096)
memory  :   f0000000-f01fffff
ioport  :   e0000000(size=268435456)
id: 
display
description:    VGA compatible controller
product:    RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
5
bus info:
pci@0000:01:05.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration:
driver  =   radeon
latency =   0
resources:
irq :   18
memory  :   e0000000-efffffff
ioport  :   1100(size=256)
memory  :   f0100000-f010ffff
memory  :   f0000000-f00fffff
memory  :   c0000-dffff
id: 
pci:1
description:    PCI bridge
product:    RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
7
bus info:
pci@0000:00:07.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   pcieport
resources:
irq :   19
memory  :   f0300000-f03fffff
id: 
usb
description:    USB controller
product:    FL1100 USB 3.0 Host Controller
vendor:     Fresco Logic
physical id:
0
bus info:
pci@0000:1f:00.0
version:    10
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pm msi pciexpress msix xhci bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   xhci_hcd
latency =   0
resources:
irq :   19
memory  :   f0300000-f030ffff
memory  :   f0310000-f0310fff
memory  :   f0311000-f0311fff
id: 
usbhost:0
product:    xHCI Host Controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic xhci-hcd
physical id:
0
bus info:
usb@8
logical name:
usb8
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-2.00
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   4
speed   =   480Mbit/s
id: 
usbhost:1
product:    xHCI Host Controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic xhci-hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@9
logical name:
usb9
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-3.00
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   4
speed   =   5000Mbit/s
id: 
pci:2
description:    PCI bridge
product:    RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
a
bus info:
pci@0000:00:0a.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   pcieport
resources:
irq :   18
memory  :   f0200000-f02fffff
id: 
network
description:    Ethernet interface
product:    NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
vendor:     Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
physical id:
0
bus info:
pci@0000:3f:00.0
logical name:
enp63s0
version:    10
serial:     2c:41:38:ba:8c:49
capacity:   1Gbit/s
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration:
autonegotiation =   on
broadcast   =   yes
driver  =   tg3
driverversion   =   3.137
firmware    =   5761-v3.77
latency =   0
link    =   no
multicast   =   yes
port    =   twisted pair
resources:
irq :   26
memory  :   f0200000-f020ffff
memory  :   f0210000-f021ffff
id: 
storage
description:    SATA controller
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
11
bus info:
pci@0000:00:11.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   ahci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   22
ioport  :   2110(size=8)
ioport  :   2120(size=4)
ioport  :   2118(size=8)
ioport  :   2124(size=4)
ioport  :   2100(size=16)
memory  :   f0409000-f04093ff
id: 
usb:0
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
12
bus info:
pci@0000:00:12.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   ohci bus_master
configuration:
driver  =   ohci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   16
memory  :   f0404000-f0404fff
id: 
usbhost
product:    OHCI PCI host controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ohci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@3
logical name:
usb3
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   3
speed   =   12Mbit/s
id: 
usb
description:    Mouse
product:    Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)
vendor:     Microsoft
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@3:1
version:    3.00
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   usbhid
maxpower    =   100mA
speed   =   2Mbit/s
id: 
usb:1
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
12.1
bus info:
pci@0000:00:12.1
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   ohci bus_master
configuration:
driver  =   ohci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   16
memory  :   f0405000-f0405fff
id: 
usbhost
product:    OHCI PCI host controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ohci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@4
logical name:
usb4
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   3
speed   =   12Mbit/s
id: 
usb
description:    Keyboard
product:    USB Keyboard
vendor:     SIGMACHIP
physical id:
2
bus info:
usb@4:2
version:    1.10
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   usbhid
maxpower    =   98mA
speed   =   2Mbit/s
id: 
usb:2
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
12.2
bus info:
pci@0000:00:12.2
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   ehci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   17
memory  :   f0409400-f04094ff
id: 
usbhost
product:    EHCI Host Controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ehci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@1
logical name:
usb1
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-2.00
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   6
speed   =   480Mbit/s
id: 
usb
description:    Wireless interface
product:    802.11 n WLAN
vendor:     Ralink
physical id:
3
bus info:
usb@1:3
logical name:
wlx9cefd5fe9eeb
version:    1.01
serial:     9c:ef:d5:fe:9e:eb
capabilities:   usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
configuration:
broadcast   =   yes
driver  =   rt2800usb
driverversion   =   4.18.0-20-generic
firmware    =   0.36
ip  =   192.168.43.125
link    =   yes
maxpower    =   450mA
multicast   =   yes
speed   =   480Mbit/s
wireless    =   IEEE 802.11
id: 
usb:3
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
13
bus info:
pci@0000:00:13.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   ohci bus_master
configuration:
driver  =   ohci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   18
memory  :   f0406000-f0406fff
id: 
usbhost
product:    OHCI PCI host controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ohci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@5
logical name:
usb5
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   3
speed   =   12Mbit/s
id: 
usb:4
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
13.1
bus info:
pci@0000:00:13.1
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   ohci bus_master
configuration:
driver  =   ohci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   18
memory  :   f0407000-f0407fff
id: 
usbhost
product:    OHCI PCI host controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ohci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@6
logical name:
usb6
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   3
speed   =   12Mbit/s
id: 
usb:5
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
13.2
bus info:
pci@0000:00:13.2
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   ehci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   19
memory  :   f0409500-f04095ff
id: 
usbhost
product:    EHCI Host Controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ehci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@2
logical name:
usb2
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-2.00
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   6
speed   =   480Mbit/s
id: 
usb:0
description:    Generic USB device
product:    VS501
vendor:     LGE
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@2:1
version:    3.18
serial:     VS501fe4e90a1
capabilities:   usb-2.00
configuration:
driver  =   usbfs
maxpower    =   500mA
speed   =   480Mbit/s
id: 
usb:1
description:    Mass storage device
product:    Cruzer
vendor:     SanDisk
physical id:
2
bus info:
usb@2:2
logical name:
scsi7
version:    1.00
serial:     FC006A86D1493221
capabilities:   usb-2.00 scsi emulated scsi-host
configuration:
driver  =   usb-storage
maxpower    =   300mA
speed   =   480Mbit/s
id: 
disk
description:    SCSI Disk
product:    Cruzer
vendor:     SanDisk
physical id:
0.0.0
bus info:
scsi@7:0.0.0
logical name:
/dev/sdc
version:    PMAP
serial:     FC006A86D1493221
size:   57GiB (61GB)
capabilities:   removable
configuration:
ansiversion =   6
logicalsectorsize   =   512
sectorsize  =   512
id: 
medium
physical id:
0
logical name:
/dev/sdc
size:   57GiB (61GB)
capabilities:   partitioned partitioned:dos
configuration:
signature   =   ecce2611
id: 
volume
description:    Windows FAT volume
vendor:     mkfs.fat
physical id:
1
logical name:
/dev/sdc1
logical name:
/media/lekcin/thumb
version:    FAT32
serial:     d8f2-41fe
size:   57GiB
capacity:   57GiB
capabilities:   primary fat initialized
configuration:
FATs    =   2
filesystem  =   fat
label   =   thumb
mount.fstype    =   vfat
mount.options   =   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro
state   =   mounted
id: 
usb:2
description:    Mass storage device
product:    ASMT1153e
vendor:     asmedia
physical id:
4
bus info:
usb@2:4
logical name:
scsi6
version:    1.00
serial:     12345678913F
capabilities:   usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
configuration:
driver  =   usb-storage
speed   =   480Mbit/s
id: 
disk
description:    SCSI Disk
product:    008-2DM166
vendor:     ST3000DM
physical id:
0.0.0
bus info:
scsi@6:0.0.0
logical name:
/dev/sdb
version:    0
serial:     F31987654321
size:   2794GiB (3TB)
capabilities:   partitioned partitioned:luks
configuration:
ansiversion =   6
logicalsectorsize   =   512
sectorsize  =   4096
id: 
volume
description:    Linux Unified Key Setup volume
physical id:
0
logical name:
/dev/sdb
serial:     13ec8e1b-bd1f-4b24-914e-b3004a032fa3
size:   2794GiB
capacity:   2794GiB
width:  256 bits
capabilities:   encrypted luks initialized
configuration:
bits    =   256
cipher  =   aes
filesystem  =   luks
hash    =   sha1
mode    =   xts-plain64
version =   1
id: 
serial
description:    SMBus
product:    SBx00 SMBus Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
14
bus info:
pci@0000:00:14.0
version:    3c
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   ht cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   piix4_smbus
latency =   0
resources:
irq :   0
id: 
multimedia
description:    Audio device
product:    SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
14.2
bus info:
pci@0000:00:14.2
version:    00
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pm bus_master cap_list
configuration:
driver  =   snd_hda_intel
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   16
memory  :   f0400000-f0403fff
id: 
isa
description:    ISA bridge
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
14.3
bus info:
pci@0000:00:14.3
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   isa bus_master
configuration:
latency =   0
id: 
pci:3
description:    PCI bridge
product:    SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
14.4
bus info:
pci@0000:00:14.4
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   pci subtractive_decode bus_master vga_palette
id: 
usb:6
description:    USB controller
product:    SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id:
14.5
bus info:
pci@0000:00:14.5
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   ohci bus_master
configuration:
driver  =   ohci-pci
latency =   32
resources:
irq :   18
memory  :   f0408000-f0408fff
id: 
usbhost
product:    OHCI PCI host controller
vendor:     Linux 4.18.0-20-generic ohci_hcd
physical id:
1
bus info:
usb@7
logical name:
usb7
version:    4.18
capabilities:   usb-1.10
configuration:
driver  =   hub
slots   =   2
speed   =   12Mbit/s
id: 
pci:1
description:    Host bridge
product:    Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
101
bus info:
pci@0000:00:18.0
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
id: 
pci:2
description:    Host bridge
product:    Family 10h Processor Address Map
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
102
bus info:
pci@0000:00:18.1
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
id: 
pci:3
description:    Host bridge
product:    Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
103
bus info:
pci@0000:00:18.2
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
id: 
pci:4
description:    Host bridge
product:    Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
104
bus info:
pci@0000:00:18.3
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
configuration:
driver  =   k10temp
resources:
irq :   0
id: 
pci:5
description:    Host bridge
product:    Family 10h Processor Link Control
vendor:     Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
physical id:
105
bus info:
pci@0000:00:18.4
version:    00
width:  32 bits
clock:  33MHz
id: 
scsi:0
physical id:
3
logical name:
scsi0
capabilities:   emulated
id: 
disk
description:    ATA Disk
product:    ST3000DM001-9YN1
vendor:     Seagate
physical id:
0.0.0
bus info:
scsi@0:0.0.0
logical name:
/dev/sda
version:    CC9B
serial:     Z1F0BAG8
size:   2794GiB (3TB)
capabilities:   gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
configuration:
ansiversion =   5
guid    =   c9f23b9b-8a35-4636-ada7-223911ec7253
logicalsectorsize   =   512
sectorsize  =   4096
id: 
volume:0
description:    BIOS Boot partition
vendor:     EFI
physical id:
1
bus info:
scsi@0:0.0.0,1
logical name:
/dev/sda1
serial:     bd5dc4e5-32e7-4740-abf1-d4b7bc03a753
capacity:   1023KiB
capabilities:   nofs
id: 
volume:1
description:    EXT4 volume
vendor:     Linux
physical id:
2
bus info:
scsi@0:0.0.0,2
logical name:
/dev/sda2
logical name:
/
version:    1.0
serial:     6b289807-f565-4fa9-80b7-2e7a19f1ebe3
size:   2794GiB
capabilities:   journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
configuration:
created =   2019-05-15 15:25:05
filesystem  =   ext4
lastmountpoint  =   /
modified    =   2019-06-12 09:15:35
mount.fstype    =   ext4
mount.options   =   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
mounted =   2019-06-12 09:16:02
state   =   mounted
id: 
scsi:1
physical id:
4
logical name:
scsi1
capabilities:   emulated
id: 
cdrom
description:    DVD reader
product:    DVD D DH16D6SH
vendor:     hp
physical id:
0.0.0
bus info:
scsi@1:0.0.0
logical name:
/dev/cdrom
logical name:
/dev/dvd
logical name:
/dev/sr0
version:    BHD4
capabilities:   removable audio dvd
configuration:
ansiversion =   5
status  =   nodisc
id: 
power
product:    Standard Efficiency
physical id:
1
capacity:   32768mWh

Comment: You should press ESC when that happens to see the error messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, the PC doesn't acknowledge any keyboard input when it is hung. The mouse still moves around.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the full hardware specifications, namely the graphics card.

Comment: You can file a bug report at launchpad.net.

Comment: I've explored launchpad.net. It looks like the sites' focus is to register free software projects. I'd appreciate any help reporting a ubuntu bug. Thanks

Comment: It often happens because of some kind of graphic card's problem or something related with it's drive. It can also happens if you have a problem in the hard disk or in the physical memory but in those circumstances it uses to show up some kind of error text.
There are some things you can do in order to certify for the offending problem. One thing is try to find some error messages in the system log (syslog) after a successful boot. Try to use dmesg and search for a clue. 
It would be useful to run some memory tests too.

Answer (score 1):

(months later...) I think I can add some light to this issue. My hard drive failed completely. I say 'completely' because it had lost some sectors over the years, as reported by Disks. When I replaced the HD, the startup issue that I reported here disappeared.