# Can I create a usb drive that boots to my hard drive?

Tags: boot, files

I'm trying to find a work-around for another question: ["Ubuntu 18.04.2 sometimes hangs from Suspend or reboot."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150384/ubuntu-18-04-2-sometimes-hangs-from-suspend-or-reboot)

My desktop boot process often hangs. Is there a way to load just the necessary boot files on a thumb drive that will boot my PC to the hard drive? I have some thumb drives that boot to an OS on themselves. But I need to boot to my hard drive.

Thanks

Comment: You can install Ubuntu (or to make it smaller and faster: Lubuntu or Xubuntu) to a USB drive like you install to an internal drive. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312). Then boot into your new system in the USB drive and run **`sudo update-grub`**. This should find your system in the internal drive and create a menu entry in the grub menu for it, and you can select to boot into it.

Comment: BIOS or UEFI? You can install grub to any drive, but generally best to have it on the same drive as your Ubuntu install. I have multiple full installs on flash drives and add to 40_custom boot of some of my HDD or SSD partitions. Use labels and configfile to boot another install
https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359 & 
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config